# Is there a control for R or tableau dashboards allowing users to enter new data and re-run the model?

Tags: r, shiny, tableau-api

I am fairly new to dashboards and wanted to get some input for a project I am working on. I work for an organization that requires me to run forecast models frequently.

As it stands today, I have a model scripted in RStudio that draws data from multiple workbooks, crunches the numbers and then outputs predicted values which are then stored in a separate workbook.

From this point on wards, I will be building a dashboard to show the actual (historical) and predicted (future) data in a nice way, possibly using a shiny dashboard. The dashboard will be shared with others within the organization which may be used for further analysis. I know how to do this.

The organization has been using a Tableau server for sometime so some integration will be involved.

However, every once in awhile I will receive a request by management to introduce new data into the forecast and report back on what the new forecast outputs would look like and provide a comparison. This is not entirely time consuming to do, but creates confusion working with multiple file versions.

Is there a simple way, a sort of control or widget, that will allow users to enter new data temporarily, run the entire forecast model in the background, and then provide a comparison, either in R (preferred) or Tableau?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`fileInput` of `shiny` is what you are looking for. Below is the example from online documentation. You can find additional details here: [File Upload Control](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/fileInput.html)

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
        accept = c(
          "text/csv",
          "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
          ".csv")
        ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.
    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much. This is great! I can work with this. I also found the numericInput function which I could possibly use to add data to the end of temp data, and then run the model out of there.